# Generate combinations (in specific order) by using one item per list in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, combinations, combinatorics

I have a rather complex problem (or so it seems to me). I have a dictionary with key-ed lists of elements and list of the keys of that dictionary

```
numbers = { 
            'group1': [1, 2],
            'group2': [3, 4],
            'group3': [5, 6]
          }
order   = [ 'group1', 'group2', 'group3' ]
```

I want to generate combinations by using **one number per group** by following the **order** given. So with the order `[ 'group1', 'group2', 'group3' ]` I expect to get

```
1, 3, 5
1, 3, 6
1, 4, 5
1, 4, 6
2, 3, 5
2, 3, 6
2, 4, 5
2, 4, 6
```

I have a solution but it's not generic enough and doesn't scale:

```
group1=order[0]
group2=order[1]
group3=order[2]
for n in numbers[group1]:
    for n2 in numbers[group2]:
        for n3 in numbers[group3]:
            print(n, n2, n3)
```

Any smarter solution that will work for an arbitrary number of groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and tuple unpacking:

```
import itertools

for ns in itertools.product(*[numbers[g] for g in order]):
    print(*ns) # or 'print ns' for 2.x
```

This gives me the result you're looking for:

```
1 3 5
1 3 6
1 4 5
1 4 6
2 3 5
2 3 6
2 4 5
2 4 6
```

Comment: What are those asterisks for?

Comment: Worth noting that `print(*ns)` doesn't work with python2.x. Use `print(ns)` instead.

Comment: If you're using Python 2.x, `print` is a statement, not a function - use `print ns`. Also, please tag your question with the appropriate version.